# Updating existing entity and then cloning the entity (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do something in Entity Framework Core
where I update an existing entity and then create a copied entity with the same properties.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var originalEntity = _context.Product
                .Include(x => x.Class)
                .Include(x => x.Type)
                .Include(x => x.Audit);

// change current product's expiration date to be today + 30
originalEntity.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);

// create a new product with updated properties but everything else same as originalEntity
var newEntity = (Product) _context.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.ToObject();

// make the property changes
// not sure if I have to do "newEntity.Id = 0;". Id is autogenerated via database
newEntity.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(90);
newEntity.Status = "ACTIVE";
newEntity.Audit = null; // don't want to make a copy of all the audit logs which is stored in a different table... is this the proper way to do so?

// track this new entity as added? I heard this won't work in Entity Framework Core if the ID is not set to null/0. Is this true?
_context.Product.Add(newEntity);

// finally commit all the changes to DB
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I made comments here and there to show my intention and confusions.

Is this the correct approach go about?

Comment: Are you asking for a suggestion or your code has a problem? (Does not save the cloned entity?)

Comment: @Steve this is something I haven't actually ran, it's more of a pseudocode i put together in my head that logically flows, but have no idea if it is proper way or even the right way to do it in EntityFrameworkCore. I also don't like the casting I am doing with `Entry.CurrentValues.ToObject()` and am wondering if there is a better/elegant way of doing it